# Postgres: check if role is part of a group

Tags: postgresql, security, roles, policy

I'm setting up a database in postgreSQL.
I've created some roles and groups, and granted some groups to role (actually I've created permissions on groups and granted groups on new users).
I enabled row level security in a table, and I want to write a policy to check if a user is part of some groups to give him permission to insert.
Something like:

```
CREATE POLICY table_policy_insert ON table
    FOR INSERT
    WITH CHECK(CURRENT_USER IS IN 'admin');
```

I've tried with `CURRENT_USER = 'admin'` but this check the exact name, so if I have a user Poo that is admin, this don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a user is part of a role using this query:

```sql
select exists(
  select b.rolname rname,
         c.rolname mname 
  from pg_auth_members a, 
       pg_roles b, 
       pg_roles c  
  where a.roleid=b.oid 
    and a.member = c.oid 
    and b.rolname = 'role_name' 
    and c.rolname = 'user_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's even nicer as a function:

```
create or replace function is_member_of (username varchar, groupname varchar) 
returns boolean as $$
  select exists (
    select 1 
    from pg_auth_members a, 
         pg_roles b, 
         pg_roles c  
    where a.roleid=b.oid 
      and a.member = c.oid 
      and b.rolname = groupname
      and c.rolname = username
  );
$$ language sql;

select is_member_of ('anna', 'admins');
```